# Does .NET 6 support pipelines of business logic - like middleware for a request, but for custom logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, pipeline

I have a number of reusable business logic steps which will be re-used in various web endpoints. I'm trying to see if there's a nice way in .NET 6 to 'chain' these reusable business logic code (think, classes where each class does just one logic step).

It's like how .NET has 'middleware' for web apps. Only in this instance, I wish to hit an endpoint then do all the steps in my custom pipeline, with the steps hardcoded for that endpoint.

here's a high level summary.

- Each 'flow' has a number of steps
- A single endpoint 'invokes' as specific flow .. which then steps through each step -until some business logic fails some check- which stops continuing and bubbles back with the error message or view.

for example.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRegistration>(_ =>
{
    new MyPipeline()
        .AddStep(newUser => ValidateUserData(newUser)) // userData is from the POST request body.
        .AddStep(user => CheckIfUserExists(user)) // Check if the user exists in the db
        .AddStep(user => CreateUser(user));
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEnrollForCourse>(_ =>
{
    new MyPipeline()
        .AddStep(user => CheckIfUserExists(user)) // Check if the user exists in the db
        .AddStep(course => CheckIfTheCourseExists(course)) // Does the uni course, exist?
        .AddStep((user, course) => EnrollUserToCourse(user, course));
});

var app = builder.Build();


app.MapPost("/register", async (NewUserModel newUser, IUserRegistration userRegistration) =>
{
    var viewResult = await userRegistration.Execute(newUser);

    return viewResult; // 200-OK | 400-BadRequest
});

app.MapPost("/enroll", async (EnrollModel enroll, IEnrollForCourse enrollForCourse) =>
{
    var viewResult = await enrollForCourse.Execute(enroll);

    retyrn viewResult; // 204-NoContent | 400-BadRequest
});

app.Run();
```

So there's heaps of problems with the above, but the general idea there.

Is this a solved problem, in .NET already? Surely this isn't new.

EDIT: Of course, I would usually just use a single class with if/else checks .. which then call the various business logic. Yes, I know. We have that -now- and if just feels really large and unwieldy and I'm trying to see if this can be refactored into nicer, re-usable components.

Also, I don't want to use Logic Apps .. which is a similar concept by Microsoft.

---

NOTE: I'm using users/course/uni etc as a simplistic example for demo/question purposes.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a workflow engine.

Comment: Any more info about what exists for .NET and are popular with the community?

Answer (score 1):

A delegate sequence builder might do the trick.

Check out this blog:
https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/09/17/how-the-next-delegate-works-in-asp-net-core-middleware.aspx

Here's a good walkthrough of the builder pattern: https://youtu.be/1JAdZul-aRQ.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jimmy Bogard’s MediatR library. You can use it to implement commands with validators and decorators.

https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

Comment: How does MediatR help, in this scenario? All I can see is that it's either request/response (which I've used plenty of times in the past -> but not valid in this scenario) or notifications (event publishing, etc) ? I guess I've misunderstood something?

Comment: See behaviors, which are very similar to Asp.net middleware: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors

Comment: But aren't these MediatR "behaviors" targetting the Request and Response? In my case, I don't really have that? This is just some normal business logic... (think -> class library)